# SparkR 2.2.0. Writing AVRO fails

Tags: r, apache-spark, avro, sparkr

I am relatively new to Spark, accessing it from SparkR, and trying to write an AVRO file to disk, but I keep getting an error saying `Task failed while writing rows`

I am running SparkR 2.2.0 -SNAPSHOT, Scala version 2.11.8, and started my SparkR session via:

```
sparkR.session(master = "spark://[some ip here]:7077",
           appName = "nateSparkRAVROTest",
           sparkHome = "/home/ubuntu/spark",
           enableHiveSupport = FALSE,
           sparkConfig = list(spark.executor.memory="28g"),
           sparkPackages =c("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3", "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34", "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0"))
```

I am wondering if I need to setup or install anything special? I include the `com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0` package in my session launching command, have seen it download the package while launching the session, and am trying to write AVRO files via this command:

```
SparkR::write.df(myFormalClassSparkDataFrameObject, path = "/home/nathan/SparkRAVROTest/", source = "com.databricks.spark.avro", mode="overwrite")
```

I'm hoping someone with more experience using SparkR has experienced this error and could provide some insight. Thank you for your time.

Kind Regards, 
Nate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using `com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0` in my Spark config.

An example SparkR config that helped is this:

```
SparkR::sparkR.session(master="local[*]", 
                   sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory="14g",
                                      spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version="2",
                                      spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs = "FALSE",
                                      spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max="1024m",
                                      spark.speculation="FALSE",
                                      spark.referenceTracking="FALSE"
                   ), 
                   sparkPackages =c("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3",
                    "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4",
                     "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.11.221",
                     "com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0",
                      "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2"))
```